# Jquery Rotate Value Starts at 0?

Tags: jquery, rotation

I have an image that when jQuery loads, it rotates right 90deg once. I would like to rotate THAT 180deg once the image is clicked for a total rotation of 270deg.

Once it is clicked again, I will add another function that rotates it back, but I can't do that until I can stop the rotation from starting at 0deg.

[JSFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92Kfb/)

```
$('#Options').click(
function () {
    //$(this).stop().animate({ 'padding-left': (GetCLWidth) });
    $('.Options_open').animate({ 90:borderSpacing: 180 }, {
        step: function (currentStep) {
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate('+ currentStep +'deg)');
            $(this).css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + currentStep + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + currentStep + 'deg)');
        },
        duration: 2500
    }, 'linear');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you do one of the following:

- after the first function completes you set a another class to position/rotate the image to its last frame after the first function executed, and start from there moving it back to the original position then trigger its first class;
- Or you can have a Boolean variable to check if this got clicked already, if it's already clicked, start a .css rotating it 180 degree, then rotate it back to its first place, but don't forget to reset the boolean variable after doing that, so you can check it over and over in both animating functions

Also since you're using CSS3 transition you should supply some functionality for browsers which lack, [**CHECK HERE**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: But that's what I'm getting at. If I rotate the picture, it starts from 0 and rotates 180deg.